# iframe onhashchange does not work

Tags: iframe, ecmascript-6

I am trying to have an iframe window's onhashchange event trigger when I change the hash from its `src` attribute. I'm testing on chrome and it's not working.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<\script>window.onhashchange = 
() => alert("wow")<\/script>'], {type: 'text/html'}))
iframe.src = url
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
iframe.src += '#bla' //nothing happens :(
iframe.src.replace(/#.*$/, '#blop') //even less happens
```

Polling the hash from inside the iframe works great, but I don't want to do that. Any thoughts?